# MongoDB: Sort and display documents in descending way

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

What is the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ID DESC` to get the latest documents as first, in reverse order for Mongoose or MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sort function on the `_id` property and `-1` as value to get them in reverse order.

```
db.getCollection('users').find().sort({_id:-1})
```